# JSONObject .key() cannot iterate in ics

Tags: java, android, json, iterator

I have a flat json... so i am using this method to iterate as suggested by many..

```
JSONObject preferencesJSON = new JSONObject(dataString);
        Iterator<String> keysIterator = preferencesJSON.keys();
        while (keysIterator.hasNext()) {
            String keyStr = (String) keysIterator.next();
            String valueStr = preferencesJSON.getString(keyStr);
            Log.e("WEB",valueStr);

        }
```

It is working fine in lollipop and above.. means that i can iterate all the obects in the loop.. but below lollipop I am getting only one object.

[image]

update on findings:

When I receive the json string i get it like this: 
    {"data":{"c_1149436":{"conte

but when I use JSONObject = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
i get this when print it: 
    {"total":269,"data":{"c_1149436"

Comment: show your Json  .

Comment: not usre if it's correct, but there is also `names()` method, returning a `JSONArray` of field names in the `JSONObject` I think it should do the trick.

Comment: but there is only one key in the  your json at root level - data...

Comment: updated the question with some new findings

Comment: POST YOUR JSON RESPONSE STRING HERE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code;

```
  private void parseJsonData1(String jsonResponse) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            if(jsonObject!=null) {
                JSONObject objData = jsonObject.optJSONObject("data");
                if(objData!=null)
                {
                    Iterator<String> iterator = objData.keys();
                    while(iterator.hasNext()){
                        String key =iterator.next();
                        JSONObject cData = objData.optJSONObject(key);
                        Log.e("WEB","value:="+cData);
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```